# Canvas draw line animation

Tags: java, android

I want to draw canvas line animation between two points. the line is working perfect but I want animation while drawing the line. The below code draw line:

```
// draw route
for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size() - 1; i++) {
    float[] goal1 = {nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).x,
            nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).y};
    float[] goal2 = {nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).x,
            nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).y};
    currentMatrix.mapPoints(goal1);
    currentMatrix.mapPoints(goal2);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(routeWidth);
    canvas.drawLine(goal1[0], goal1[1], goal2[0], goal2[1], paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way. Try following link [enter link description here](https://github.com/sajibremix/Animated_Draw_Line)

Function demo

```js
(function () {
   var lastTime = 0;
   var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
   for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
   }
   if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
    var id = window.setTimeout(function () {
     callback(currTime + timeToCall);
    },
    timeToCall);
    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
    return id;
   };
   if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
    clearTimeout(id);
   };
  }());
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  // variable to hold how many frames have elapsed in the animation
  var t = 1;
  // define the path to plot
  var vertices = [];
  vertices.push({
   x: 0,
   y: 0
  });
  vertices.push({
   x: 300,
   y: 100
  });
  vertices.push({
   x: 80,
   y: 200
  });
  vertices.push({
   x: 10,
   y: 100
  });
  vertices.push({
   x: 0,
   y: 0
  });
  // draw the complete line
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  // tell canvas you are beginning a new path
  ctx.beginPath();
  // draw the path with moveTo and multiple lineTo's
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(80, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(10, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  // stroke the path
  ctx.stroke();
  // set some style
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  // calculate incremental points along the path
  var points = calcWaypoints(vertices);
  // extend the line from start to finish with animation
  animate(points);
  // calc waypoints traveling along vertices
  function calcWaypoints(vertices) {
   var waypoints = [];
   for (var i = 1; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    var pt0 = vertices[i - 1];
    var pt1 = vertices[i];
    var dx = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    var dy = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
     var x = pt0.x + dx * j / 100;
     var y = pt0.y + dy * j / 100;
     waypoints.push({
      x: x,
      y: y
     });
    }
   }
   return (waypoints);
  }
  function animate() {
   if (t < points.length - 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   }
   // draw a line segment from the last waypoint
   // to the current waypoint
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(points[t - 1].x, points[t - 1].y);
   ctx.lineTo(points[t].x, points[t].y);
   ctx.stroke();
   // increment "t" to get the next waypoint
   t++;
  }
```

```css
body {
   background-color: ivory;
  }
  canvas {
   border:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: can you please explain in java or android?